# Switch language in Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, internationalization, cakephp-3.0

In my bootstrap.php I am using

```
DispatcherFactory::add('LocaleSelector');
ini_set('intl.default_locale', 'en_US');
```

Now I want to create a language Switch, I tried this in my routes.php

```
Router::addUrlFilter(function ($params, $request) {
    if (isset($request->params['lang']) && !isset($params['lang'])) {
        $params['lang'] = $request->params['lang'];
    } elseif (!isset($params['lang'])) {
        $params['lang'] = 'en'; // set your default language here
    }
    return $params;
});

Router::scope('/:lang/*', function ($routes) {
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);
});
```

And calling it in the home.ctp

```
<?= $this->Html->link(__('Englisch'), ['lang' => 'de']);?>
```

Also I was looking at - http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html - but I wasnt able to figure out what to do.

Comment: For language based routing you can checkout https://github.com/ADmad/cakephp-i18n#using-the-i18nroute

Comment: Hey thanks. Whats the difference between using the database and the .po files?

Comment: Its probably a little overkill, as I just want to have the option for the user to switch the language, if he wants to.

Comment: @ADmad can you show an example entry for the Database?(https://github.com/ADmad/cakephp-i18n)

Comment: Also can I just use my .po files instead?

Comment: Sure you can. You don't have to use all features of the plugin. For languages based URLs just use the I18nRoute.